# $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

I try to prove if de groups $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ are isomorphic.
I was using the fact that $ \mathbb{Z}_ {mn} $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n $ if and only if $ (m, n) = 1 $ taking $ m = n = p $,in this case as $ p $ is a prime greater than 1, then $ (p, p) = p \neq 1 $ and so I don't have the isomorphism, but I don't know if this is true.

Comment: The cyclic group $C_n$ has an element of order $n$.  Does $C_p\times C_p$ has an element of order $p^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\times \mathbb{Z}/p$. By definition, the former is the cyclic group of order $p^2$, which implies that it has a generating element of order $p^2$. Any element of $\mathbb{Z}/p\times \mathbb{Z}/p$ is of form $(a,b)$, with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}/p$. But observe that $p(a,b)=(pa, pb)=(0,0)$, so the order of any such $(a,b)$ is at most $p$. Since isomorphisms preserve order, no such isomorphism is possible.

Comment: In this case, is the notation $ \mathbb{Z} / p $. Is the same that $\mathbb{Z}_{p} $, that is, are the integers modulo p?

Comment: @randal Yes; this is the case.

Comment: ok, I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

It is.  The statement $\Bbb Z_m\times\Bbb Z_n\cong\Bbb Z_{mn}$ is equivalent to $(m,n)=1$.

Comment: I meant it's true that the OP doesn't have an isomorphism.  The OP asked if that was true.

Comment: There are loads of times when the statements of the problems on this site are not terribly precise.  @peterag  messy, convoluted, near nonsense.  I'm used to it.  But I believe that has something to do with (trying to do) mathematics.  Sometimes they get cleaned up; alot of times they don't.